# kubernetes : what is happening between Initialized and Ready?

Tags: kubernetes

I am using argo, a solution to orchestrate pods dynamically

I am facing a problem where there are long seconds between 2 pods

I trace it down to the k8s responsibility thanks to the following command : `k get pods -o name | grep rt-coverage | xargs -n 1 -I{} kubectl get {} -o jsonpath="{.metadata.name}{','}{range .status.conditions[*]}{.type}{','}{.lastTransitionTime}{'\n'}{end}"`

the output is a bit crude and looks like (I added the empty lines manually)

```
rt-coverage-gbsz2-1241035201,Initialized,2021-07-01T15:52:54Z
Ready,2021-07-01T15:53:03Z
ContainersReady,2021-07-01T15:53:03Z
PodScheduled,2021-07-01T15:52:54Z

rt-coverage-gbsz2-1342292650,Initialized,2021-07-01T15:52:24Z
Ready,2021-07-01T15:52:44Z
ContainersReady,2021-07-01T15:52:44Z
PodScheduled,2021-07-01T15:52:24Z

rt-coverage-gbsz2-2987741140,Initialized,2021-07-01T15:53:17Z
Ready,2021-07-01T15:53:22Z
ContainersReady,2021-07-01T15:53:22Z
PodScheduled,2021-07-01T15:53:17Z
```

You can have a look to the obfusctaed pod.yaml and to the statuses on this gist : https://gist.github.com/christopheblin/b06018d33faa84f2d5ba1e9e538b2381

I always have PodScheduled=Initialized and Ready=ContainersReady, but the time between Initialized and Ready varies between 3s and 25s (here we have 5s for last pod and 20s for second pod)

I found out that between the 2, there is the images pulling (which roughly takes 3s - 4s)

But what else ?

I tried to use the `k get event` but it is damn impossible to have the "raw" view of events with precise timestamps (you only see successfully pulled image but where is the rest ?)

I also tried to look in the K8s doc but except https://kubernetes.io/fr/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/ which is pretty "scarse", there is nothing about this...

Does anyone knows a way to have insights into what is happening exactly inside a pod between intialized and ready ?

Is this something related to k8s or simply to a docker image ?

Edit : add gist for pod.yaml and pod.statuses.txt

Comment: Are there readyness probes there?

Comment: @zerkms I added a gist to the pod.yaml so you can see (from my pov, there is no readiness probe here)

Comment: Another thing could be a `my-volume` PVC mounting taking that long. What provisions it? Have you checked its logs as well?

Comment: @zerkms it is an azurefile PVC in ReadWriteMany. I search the docs and google, but I cannot find a way to see some logs about that. Do you have pointers ?

Comment: I never used Azure: but there should be a pod (managed by daemonset?) running on the host that mounts it. Presumably https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/azurefile-csi-driver ?